# Stand alone jython JMX client for WebSphere Application Server 7.0 using SOAP

Tags: jmx, websphere-7, jython-2.5

I'm trying to write a stand alone jython JMX client to monitor WebSphere Application Server. It connects to the DMGR using SOAP and SSL.

The code works when running it w/ WSADMIN, but fails when trying to run it as a stand alone jython client. This makes me believe the code is correct and that I'm missing a JAR or configuration file when trying to run it as a stand alone client. Also, this works w/ SSL disabled.

I have the following questions:

1. How can I establish the connection with security enabled (so with SSL)?
2. How can I make my client run from another machine? (which jars are needed?)

WAS Version:
7.0.0.21 ND on Solaris

```
import java.util.Properties as Properties
import javax.management.ObjectName as ObjectName
import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient as AdminClient
import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory as AdminClientFactory

class DeploymentManager:
    def __init__(self, host, soapport, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.soapport = soapport
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

def create_admin_client(dmgrhost, dmgrsoapport, user, password):
    props = Properties()
    props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP)
    props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, dmgrhost)
    props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, dmgrsoapport)
    props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
    props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, user);
    props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, password);
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                      "/opt/IBM/Profiles/dmgr01/etc/DummyClientTrustFile.jks");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
                      "/opt/IBM/Profiles/dmgr01/etc/DummyClientKeyFile.jks");

    adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props)

    return adminClient

def get_servers():
    servers = [s for s in adminClient.queryNames(queryName, None).toArray()]

    return servers

def get_server_states(servers):
    serverstates = {}
    for server in servers:
        name = adminClient.getAttribute(server, "name")
        pid = adminClient.getAttribute(server, "pid")
        state = adminClient.getAttribute(server, "state")
        serverstates[name] = {'name' : name, 'state' : state, 'pid' : pid}

    return serverstates

DMGRs = []
DMGRs.append(DeploymentManager('dmgr1_host', 'dmgr1_soap_port', 'dmgr1_user', 'dmgr1_pw'))
DMGRs.append(DeploymentManager('dmgr2_host', 'dmgr2_soap_port', 'dmgr2_user', 'dmgr2_pw'))
DMGRs.append(DeploymentManager('dmgr3_host', 'dmgr3_soap_port', 'dmgr3_user', 'dmgr3_pw'))

for DMGR in DMGRs:
    adminClient = create_admin_client(DMGR.host, DMGR.soapport, DMGR.user, DMGR.password)
    queryName = ObjectName("WebSphere:*,node=*,type=Server,name=srv*")

    servers = get_servers()
    serverstates = get_server_states(servers)

    print '## %s ##' % DMGR.host
    keys = serverstates.keys()
    keys.sort()
    for key in keys:
        print '%s %s: %s' % (serverstates[key]['name'],
                             serverstates[key]['pid'],
                             serverstates[key]['state'])

    print
```

Here's the error I see when I run it:

```
jython -Dpython.path=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar -Dcom.ibm.SOAP.ConfigURL=/opt/IBM/Profiles/dmgr01/properties/soap.client.props was_common.py
Apr 16, 2012 3:07:39 PM com.ibm.ws.management.connector.interop.JMXClassLoader
WARNING: Could not find tmx4jTransform.jar in null/etc/tmx4jTransform.jar - Interoperability to older versions of WebSphere is disabled
Apr 16, 2012 3:07:40 PM com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
INFO: ssl.disable.url.hostname.verification.CWPKI0027I
Apr 16, 2012 3:07:40 PM com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator
INFO: Client code attempting to load security configuration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "was_common.py", line 56, in <module>
    adminClient = create_admin_client(DMGR.host, DMGR.soapport, DMGR.user, DMGR.password)
  File "was_common.py", line 30, in create_admin_client
    adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:632)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClientFactory.java:123)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFactory.java:206)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException:     com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host dmgr1_host at port dmgr1_soap_port
```

Note:  I changed some values in this example to generic values.

Comment: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host dmgr1_host at port dmgr1_soap_port. Did you check SOAP ports are enabled (or) exists on Websphere?

Comment: Yes, I've verified the SOAP ports exist and are enabled.  As I mentioned, I can run this same code w/ wsadmin and it works fine.  It will connect to all the DMGRs (on different hosts) that I have listed and display the server statuses.

Comment: Edited code to correct cut/paste mistake.  Setting javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword and javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword isn't necessary and throws errors.

Comment: I was have the same problem. For me the error was because my url  beginning with the protocol  `http://myip.compute.amazonaws.com`  changed to `myip.compute.amazonaws.com`